# Map all fields as one field in other class Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to build following json structure via my objects

```json
{ 
  Id:"123",
  Name:"me",
  Attributes:[{x:"test1",value:{value1:"1"},{x:"test2",value:[{abc:"somevalue"}]}}
]
```

Attributes size will be fixed and value of x would be same in each request.

What would be ideal structure of classes in jackson mapping

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a structure like this would do.
Of course you'll need some additional annotations to ensure the fields have the proper names, and you'll also want to ass getters and setters.

```
class Outer{
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Attribute> attributes;
}

class Attribute{
    String x;
    Map<String, String> values;
}
```